# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am getting these error on my page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'revolution'
```

In my page, the theme I am using already used one jQuery library, but FancyBox is using another customized jQuery library for itself. Here are my head details:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" media="screen">

<!---->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
```

I searched for this problem using Google, but no solution worked for it.

Comment: Check your paths, it seems fancybox js is not loading. Also, you don't need two instances of jQuery, fancybox will work with the single version you use for other plugins (**fancybox doesn't use a customized jQuery library for itself**)

Comment: Anytime you have these errors, it is also a conflict, or referencing issue. 99% of time if using right out of the package libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check using `$.noConflict()`. I have faced this issue earlier. Load the first library, and save it under a different name say.

`window.oldJquery = $.noConfilict()` ans then load the new jQuery. Use both and when you need it, if you are using old jQuery, use `oldJquery`instead of `$`.

Comment: That is a great idea. For about "noConflict".

Comment: +1 : or maybe just replacing the alias `$` by `jQuery`. The OP isn't showing its custom fancybox initialization but that might be another source of the issue. Although he may not need two versions of jQuery

Comment: Main problem is that <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> is needed for the theme. Without this library the theme falls apart. So i cant ignore that one.

Comment: @WillY : try removing  `<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` but don't keep both

Comment: @JFK if i remove <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> fancybox wont work. Any other way?

Comment: @WillY : it might be the case when one jQuery version is too old for some plugins and too new for others. Why don't you try [jQuery v1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) only?, which I think will work for all your plugins (and remove the two other instances of jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the FancyBox library, but this occurs if your references are not in the correct order. So that library might be dependent on a later library you reference, or it is being globbered. Move your reference to it later in the references link.

I would assume your jQuery library is too old for this, or your library for jQuery is not actually being referenced.